# How to convert HLS to UDP on FFmpeg or any other freeware?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, streaming, udp, hls

What freeware can I use to convert an HLS playlist to a UDP stream? I tried FFmpeg on hls url to udp stream, which worked. I'm trying to find a freeware that can manage to do the same, but with multiple hls url links or an hls playlist. Something fascinating and useful (to my case) I found in FFmpeg was that I can input HLS and manage to output UDP through the ethernet port.

Here bellow is an example I used for FFmpeg. I want to think that the issue of not being able to input the playlist is the "s" on "https". Any recommendations or advice would be helpful. I would like to keep using the FFmpeg software, but if there isn't any solution, I would need to use other software.

```
ffmpeg -i https://hls_source -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -c:a aac -s 1280x720 -f mpegts -bufsize 4000k -max_delay 1000000 -fflags nobuffer udp://destination_ip:port?pkt_size=1316
```

Comment: Send the output of `ffmpeg -buildconf`